Would Partial Indexes allow quering the data
Assumming we have 3 columns which are relevant for partion : key1 , key2 and lastupdateddate.
when we delete a lot of records from collection (~billion of records) , the index {key1:1,key2:1,lastupdateddate:1} is rebuilding constantly and consumes huge amount of cpu and disk.
We are considering to partition the index. , e.g create
{key1: 1, key2: 1 }, { partialFilterExpression: { lastupdateddate: { $lte: new Date("2024-07-01T00:00:00Z")$gt: new Date("2024-06-01T00:00:00Z") } } }

{key1: 1, key2: 1 }, { partialFilterExpression: { lastupdateddate: { $lte: new Date("2024-06-01T00:00:00Z")$gt: new Date("2024-05-01T00:00:00Z") } } }

and so on.
Would this partial indexes be sufficient to query for the data based on key1 and key2?

The index shouldn't rebuild just because you deleted some records.  What triggered it to rebuild?

What is your delete pattern? For such amount of data, it could be useful to create (for example) one partition per day. When data is not needed anymore, then drop the entire collection. This will be much faster. Did you consider TTL Index?

@WernfriedDomscheit the problem is that we need to delete records that has not been updated for some period and not that was created at some time

@Joe of course they should...any insertion ,update or deletion of record changes the data which in turn changes indexes based on that data...

Add a field which shows the last update time and use TTL index on that.

@WernfriedDomscheit ttl index does not makes it and starts running behind,therefore we are searching for other options
